# Light speed comunications

Tags: internal-consistency, physics, faster-than-light

Suppose that a ship is traveling from the earth, point A, to Pluto, point B. That travel is at speed of light, or close to it. They comunicate by radio or laser back to earth. Since the ship is at speed of light, the data transmitted to earth, point A, is lost in pieces in space and never reach its destination?

Comment: I don’t think there’s anything more here than theory… Objects with mass can’t travel at the speed of light, and nothing we know of could get close, so we pretty much have to guess

Comment: Other than the choice to have the ship traveling *at* the speed of light (forbidden by modern physics, as opposed to the usual phrasing of being "close" to the speed of light, like 99.9999999% of the speed of light), this is actually one of the very basic special relativity problems.  It's one of the first that you explore when learning SR.  As a result, if you want to delve further into what happens and why, Physics.SE would be able to help you out best (assuming you're willing to travel just shy of the speed of light, of course)

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding. As others have pointed out, your question is not easily answerable; as such it might be [closed or put on hold](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). If that happens, then it's not the end of the question. If you edit it to be more easily answerable, then you can request it to be reopened again.

Comment: @Mrkvička it's not hard to answerable, it's based on false premise, and answer of LSerni pretty much clarifies that. So, it just a flawed question and nothing more.

Answer (score 13):

Relativistic speeds behave oddly. If observer A is on a 250 km/h train, and throws a stone backwards at 50 km/h, they sees the stone having a velocity of 50 km/h, but someone standing on the embankment sees that same stone as having the speed of observer A **minus** the speed relative to observer A: thus 200 km/h. The speed is not the same *relative* to the two observers. At higher speeds, the addition formula behaves differently: observer A, traveling at 0.9 c relative to observer B, throws a particle forward at 0.2 c relative to themselves. The particle moves at 0.2 c relative to observer A, *but it does not move at 0.9+0.2 = 1.1c relative to observer B* but, just to say a number, at 0.95c ([here the exact math with the true results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula)).

So, "throwing a signal back" will not "lose" it.

The signal sent to Earth travels at the speed of light, of course. Being sent from a vehicle which is itself traveling at the speed of light (or rather, close to it), it will be exceptionally red-shifted and weakened, just as a siren from an ambulance running away from you is perceived at a lower pitch because of the Doppler effect.

Seen from a different perspective: at close to the speed of light time, slows down to a crawl. The people in the ship send a message, and the message takes five of *their* seconds to send, and uses ten watts of power. Which means fifty Joules of energy.

From the point of view of Earth, the sending of the message took eight hours, but consisted of those same fifty Joules of energy. Spread in eight hours (8*3600 = 28800 seconds), that gives 50/28800 = *1.73 milliwatt* of power.

Also, Earth rotates while the message arrives, and the apparent source is streaking through the sky, rising and setting every 24 hours.

So, the message will be much more difficult to receive, but it's still there, and recoverable, if one has the technology.

Comment: One idea is transmit your signal from the spaceship using very high energy photons, like hard x-rays or something like that. Then the red shift will bring it to something not too far red-shifted so it will be more easily detectable. Another idea: You put your message on a radio beacon and shoot this beacon back at relativistic speed toward Earth. The beacon speed with respect to Earth is not so high, and it can transmit a recorded message by radio waves that would not be significantly altered.

Comment: @MolbOrg Why protons? Who was talking about protons?

Comment: @MaximUmansky my crappy eyes won't read correctly, yes sorry, I remove the objection.